# Query on displaying static row numbers in QTableView in a certain application

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have an application , in which I have a `QWidget`. This QWidget is divided into two parts using a `QSplitter` with vertical orientation.

The two parts are :

- `QTreeWidget` on the left ;
- `QTableView` on the right.

The model used in QTableView is inherited from QAbstractTableModel.

When I select a row in QTreeWidget, the QTableView on the right should be updated. The QtableView should display the row numbers in ascending order and one column should display the object names. To display the row numbers, I am using `setHeaderData` of QAbstractTablemodel for vertical headers
I am facing some issues in using that function.

**Issues**
  I am also using `QSortFilterProxyModel` to sort the column of object names. The issue I am facing is that when I sort the column with object names by clicking on horizontal header of the column and then I select the row, the row number in the vertical header changes.

**Is there any way to display the row numbers in the verticalwithout change, while sorting the object names columns?**

Comment: This is not a solution, a quick and a dirty fix. Assuming that the vertical headers contain just numbers, you can always reset the vertical headers after the sorting. Or perhaps, use a custom `QHeaderView` which restores itself to the original state whenever there is a change. The signal you'd want to check would be [`QHeaderView::sectionMoved(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sectionMoved)

Comment: Could you provide an example code for the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My work-around:
setup two QTableViews next to each other. The one on the left uses the unsorted model. The QTableView on the right uses the sorting proxy model.
Now add a column in the (unsorted) model that returns the row +1.
Hide this column in the right table. Hide all but this column in the left table.
Now you only need to tweak UI so spacing isn't an issue.
If your table on the right scrolls, you must sync that event to the table on the right.